# "not a supported wheel on this platform" error installing pyodbc on Windows 10

Tags: python, pyodbc

This has been asked before and there are some git threads also online, but none of these solutions are working for me and I can't figure out why.

I'm running windows 10 and have a python Flask project running inside a venv. I need to connect to a SQL Server database to retrieve data and so I am trying to install PYODBC.

Running

```
pip install pyodbc
```

does not work as it throws an error that it seems many others have run into.

The suggested solution is to download an unofficial wheel from  [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc)

I've tried both of the python 3.10 wheels:

- pyodbc‑4.0.32‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
- pyodbc‑4.0.32‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl

but in both cases pip throws another error saying 'not a supported wheel on this platform'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact steps to reproduce the issue. [This](https://pastebin.com/dCmZyLNc) works fine for me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? the question already describes the exact steps. Download the wheel and try to install it... it fails with not supported wheel error. Not much more to it.

Comment: You don't mention whether you are running `pip install` from within your (activated) venv. You also don't mention if you are trying to do it in WSL or native Windows.

Comment: You also don't mention any error message you receive. "doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your venv is apparently not running the version of Python that you think it is. For example, if my venv is running 64-bit Python 3.9 and I try to install the wheel for 64-bit Python 3.10 I get the error

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Gord\git\so74122423> pip install .\pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Different venvs can be running different versions of Python. You can verify the actual version for your venv with

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Gord\git\so74122423> python -VV
3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```